# Express: Minify CSS/JS from remote URL with UglifyJS

Tags: node.js, express

I managed to get the data on #1, but I can't print it out in Express #2, how can I resolve the data and output it?

I believe this is my code error where I can't place the correct async/await.

Here's my code:

**minify.js**

```
const { getContent } = require('./get');
const { minifyJS } = require('./processing');

async function getMinify(req, res) {
  try {
    const remoteUrl = 'http://example.com/script.js';

    console.log('URL: ' + remoteUrl);

    // #1
    const content = await getContent(remoteUrl);

    // #2
    const outputJS = await minifyJS(content);
    res.end(outputJS);

  } catch (error) {
    res.end(error.content);
  }
}

module.exports = { getMinify }
```

**get.js**

```
const got = require('got');

async function getContent(remoteUrl) {
  const code = await got(remoteUrl);
  return code.body;
}

module.exports = { getContent }
```

**processing.js**

```
const { minify } = require('uglify-js');

async function minifyJS(data) {
  const result = await minify(data);

  return result.code;
}

module.exports = { minifyJS }
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const { getMinify } = require('./minify');

const app = express();

app.get('/*', getMinify);

app.listen(5000);
```

Comment: please added `script.js` file for testing code, I need

Comment: or give me a URL for testing

Comment: if your issue solved, please accept and upvote my answer bro, thank you

Comment: accept if you got the answer please

Answer (score 0):

based on [uglify-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js), result of `minify(data)` function has two object `code` and `error`.

and `minify(data)` don't need to `await`

**processing.js** should changed

```
const { minify } = require("uglify-js");
async function minifyJS(data) {
  let { error, code } = minify(data);
  if (error) 
    throw error;
    
  return code;
}
module.exports = { minifyJS };
```

and for handling of two .js file (get.js and processing.js) changed
**minify.js**

```
  try {
    const remoteUrl = 'http://example.com/script.js';

    console.log('URL: ' + remoteUrl);

    // #1
    const content = await getContent(remoteUrl);

    // #2
    const outputJS = await minifyJS(content);
    res.end(outputJS);

  } catch (error) {
    res.end(error); // remove .content
  }
```